# Understand make wildcard function

Tags: gnu-make

A lot of people suggest using `wildcard` to check if a file exists. So I tried the following command which works in my makefile:

```
TMPDIR= .tmp
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(TMPDIR)/flag))
    find_flag_file = yes
endif
```

However, if I try to use the temp variable `$(1)` in the `wildcard` function, it doesn't return true when the file exists:

```
TMPDIR= .tmp
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(TMPDIR)/$(1)_flag))
    find_flag_file = yes
endif
```

Instead, I have to use a `*` before `$(1)` to make the above code work:

```
TMPDIR= .tmp
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(TMPDIR)/*$(1)_flag))
    find_flag_file = yes
endif
```

Could someone please explain to me why I need a `*` here in the `wildcard` matching.

Comment: I don't know what you think _the temp variable `$(1)`_ is, but it's not anything special in the makefile examples you've provided.  It just expands to the empty string, so you're looking for `.tmp/_flag` which presumably doesn't exist.  Then when you add the `*` you're searching for `.tmp/*_flag` which clearly exists.

Comment: What are you putting in `$(1)`? Without knowing what you area putting in here this is unanswerable. @MadScientist's comment is probably the explanation, but without knowing what you are doing with it this doesn't seem to be answerable.